# Making module run an action on another module before compiling in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
root
  module A
    build.gradle
  module B
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

I need to run a task from `module B` before compiling `module A`

I need to run the task "run" from module B before building module A

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an explicit task dependency from, say, A's `compileJava` task on B's `run` task. However, in general a project shouldn't reach out into the build model of another project. So the question becomes, why do you need this to happen, and would there be a cleaner way to model it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, A is an android project, B is a generator for DAO classes (using GreenDAO). I want to run the generator for the DAO classes before compiling A, so that A has the DAO classes.

Comment: What is the syntax for explicitly adding a dependency across modules?

Comment: That would usually be modeled by A having some sort of compile dependency on B, i.e. artifact dependency rather than explicit task dependency.

Comment: Ok, the thing is that the generator generates the .java files, it does not contain the classes itself. That's why i was gunning for this approach.